# Bitcoin block and transaction regex

Tags: regex, bitcoin

I want to be able to determine if a given hash represents a block, block height or transaction.

I know block are like ^[0-9]+$ and that ^0$ is valid since it's the genesis block.
I know a block is in base58 with a length of 64 and usually starts with a 0.
I know a transaction is in base58 with a length of 64.

Now I ended up with regex:

- block height: ^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
- block hash: ^0+[BASE58]{63}$
- transaction hash: ^[BASE58]{64}$

Yet I spotted some transactions with leading 0 so I guess it's not part of the Bitcoin protocol to have only blocks to start with 0s.
I also run a regtest local (fake) network with difficulty=1 and all blocks do not start with 0s.

Is there any reliable way, most probably using regex, to differentiate a block hash from a transaction hash?

Comment: No idea about bitcoin, but you probably should remove the `+` in your block hash regex, otherwise it would allow more than one zero at the start and still have 63 base58 characters afterwards.

Comment: Bitcoin's difficulty forces blocks to be mined by finding a hash with leading zeros, so that's intentional. But this regex leads to problems I exposed.

Comment: If it is not the pattern of each individual hash that distinguish a block from a transaction, than it must be the order, I guess. How do you distinguish them (visually)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main problems you will need to tackle: the first, and easier one, is the format of a transaction or block hash. These are SHA256 hashes of the corresponding serialized representations of the transaction or a block, meaning that these are just 32 byte arrays, commonly represented in hexadecimal to users. The regular expression to check validity for both therefore is simply

```
^[a-fA-F0-9]{64}$
```

as you noted blocks in Bitcoin (though not other cryptocurrencies such as litecoin) will have leading zeroes, with at least 8 zeroes due to the minimum difficulty, you could therefore also use the following:

```
^[0]{8}[a-fA-F0-9]{56}$
```

though keep in mind that transactions may also fall in that category, since they will on occasion produce a hash with leading zeroes (in expectation every 1/4294967296th transaction will have such a hash).

The second, much harder, problem is to check whether the hash actually corresponds to a transaction or block. Think of it like this, while there are many valid e-mail addresses, only very few of them will actually correspond actual users. To perform this check you'd have to either have a complete copy of the blockchain and look for the matching items, or you can have another datastructure, e.g., index or bloomfilter, to check that such an item actually exists.

Comment: Ok I was not sure the leading 0s could be safely took as a hard-rule. And I guess I'll have to call the RPC to check if such transaction exists for the second (harder) problem.